# C++ Nested for loop for exponents with set base/exponent

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops, exponent

So I need some help with this. I want to print out all integers between 2 and 2^20 that are integer powers of 2. I figured out that I need to increase the power by 1 each time but I can't seem to figure out what goes inside the inner for loop. I cannot use the pow() function

```
c = 2;    
cout << "\nPROBLEM C" << endl;
for (int powerC = 1; powerC <= 20; powerC++) // powerC is exponent
{ 
  cout << setw(5) << powerC << " ";
  counterC++;
  for (int x = 1; x <= 20; x++) // where I am having trouble with
  {
     c = (c*powerC);
     cout << setw(5) << c;
  } // end inner for loop
    if (counterC % 8 == 0)
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
}
cout << "\nNumber of numbers = " << counterC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much simpler by using the `<<` operator.

Since 2 is 2^1, you want to print all integers from 2^1 to 2^20 inclusively, or 20 numbers:

```
int c = 2;
for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    std::cout << c << std::endl;

    c <<= 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. However, I want to ask what exactly the     << operator does. I have never seen that before

Comment: It's the left shift operator, look it up. You can simply replace that with "c=c*2". Same thing.